# saving document in text format from rtf document using aspose

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

I am using Aspose words to convert the rtf document into text document. While saving does work fine, i see some issues with the format. There is blank line in the first line of the text file which is not there in the rtf document and when i used Jacob earlier, the lines are wrapped which is not happening in aspose. Are there any options to address this ?

Comment: I suggest you please upgrade to the [latest version of Aspose.Words 16.2.0](http://www.aspose.com/downloads/words-family/net) and see how it goes on your end. In case the problem still remains, please report this issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Upgrading didn't work. I just posted the issue in Aspose forum.